# How to fetch uiview object parameters

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview, uiimageview

I have an array of `UIview` and `UIImageView` objects. if i print those objects in console i am getting the output in this manner

`UIImageView: 0x9ac9830; frame = (327 155; 30 30); opaque = NO; userInteractionEnabled = NO; tag = 1560; layer = CALayer: 0x9ac98b0`

Now i would like to fetch parameters upto this `UIImageView`: `0x9ac9830`. if anyone know please let me know the way thanks in advance.

Comment: what parameters you want from the views ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For example, you have UIView *view1.

If you want to see the properties that UIView and print it out, you should:

```
NSLog(@"View has this property:%@", view1.
```

When you stop at the dot, Xcode itself will pop out the different properties that is available for you to choose from.

Hope this helps...

Comment: Hi lakesh thanks a lot for your reply. But xcode is not popup any opetions after ".". Please let me know how to access the properties of the object.